# Чем отличается SQL Server от SQL Server Utility

Tags: sql-server

[Смотрю](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) ограничения и вижу такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос, чем отличается SQL Server от SQL Server Utility?

Например, у меня на одном из экземпляров уже вышел за 50 баз.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю под SQL Server`ом понимается единица установленных копий, а под SQL Server Utility, служебное ПО для администрирования.

Служебная программа SQL Server моделирует сущности организации, связанные с SQL Server, в унифицированном представлении. С помощью точек обзора программы SQL Server и обозревателя программ в среде Среда SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) администраторы получают целостное представление об исправности ресурсов SQL Server. Для этого используется экземпляр SQL Server, служащий точкой управления служебной программой (UCP). В точке управления служебной программой SQL Server могут отображаться следующие сущности:

- Экземпляры SQL Server
- Приложения уровня данных
- Файлы базы данных
- Тома хранилища

Подробнее: [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ee210548(v=sql.105)).

Таким образом документация говорит о том, что возможности SQL Server Utility ограничены 1000ей пользовательских БД.

Comment: Немного не понимаю. Я же когда создаю БД я ее создаю в рамках конкретного экземпляра.

Comment: Все верно, откройте Utility Explorer. То о чем вы спрашиваете и есть ограничения на отображения ваших мощностей.